# Accordion card issue when inside JS array

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, json

I currently have this list that properly displays each row of the database. The issue is that the accordion feature doesn't work when put into the JS array, however, it works when directly put in HTML. I'm confused as to what I'm doing wrong here to cause it to fail to execute the accordion feature. Would like to understand why this isn't working and how to fix it. Thanks.

Here is the JS:

```
<script>
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordionList");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("activeLink");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
        panel.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
        panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
        } 
    });
    }

    $(function() {
        var records = [];
        $.getJSON('https://v1.nocodeapi.com/devmarq/airtable/RiBnzHulmTPHkgnD?tableName=JobListings&fields=company,logo,img,companyDescription,role,roleDescription,location,link,dateAdded&view=AllListings', function(data) {
            $.each(data.records, function parseJSON(i, { fields: f }) {
                var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + "<div style='padding-top: 1%; padding-bottom: 1%;'>" + "<div style='border: 1px solid black;'>" + "<button class='accordionList' style='font-size: large; outline: none;'>" + "<span style='padding-top: 2.5%; padding-bottom: 3%;'>" + "<img src='" + f.logo + "' height='30px'>" + "</span> &nbsp;<span style='padding-top: 3%; padding-bottom: 3%;'>&nbsp;&nbsp; " + f.company + " &nbsp; | &nbsp; " + f.role + " &nbsp;&nbsp; <span style='color: #2b2b2b;''><span class='iconify-inline' data-icon='eva:pin-outline' style='color: #2b2b2b;'></span> " + f.location +"</span></span>" + "</td>" + "</tr>" + "</button>" + "<div class='panel'>" + "<br>" + "<p style='color: #505050;'>Posted: " + f.dateCreated + " &nbsp; | &nbsp; Status: " + f.status + "</p>" + "<h4>About this role:</h4>" + "<p>" + f.roleDescription + "</p>" + "<h4>About " + f.company + ":</h4>" + "<p>" + f.companyDescription + "</p>" + "<br>" + "<a href='pricing.html' class='button btn btn-lg btn-block btn-sm button-black' style='padding-top: 1%; padding-bottom: 1%; width: 200px;'>Apply &nbsp; <span class='iconify-inline' data-icon='bi:arrow-right-circle' data-width='15' style='color: white;'></span></a>" + "<br>" + "</div>" + "</div>" + "</div>" + "</td>" + "</tr>"

                $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<table id="userdata" style="width: 100%;">
    <tbody id="jobsData">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="padding-top: 1%; padding-bottom: 1%;">
                    <div style="border: 1px solid black;">
                        <button class="accordionList" style="font-size: large; outline: none;">
                            <span style="padding-top: 2.5%; padding-bottom: 3%;"><img src="[LOGO]" height="30px"></span>&nbsp;<span style="padding-top: 3%; padding-bottom: 3%;">&nbsp;&nbsp; [COMPANY] &nbsp; | &nbsp; [ROLE] &nbsp;&nbsp; <span style="color: #2b2b2b;"><span class="iconify-inline" data-icon="eva:pin-outline" style="color: #2b2b2b;"></span> [LOCATION]</span></span>
                        </button>
                        <div class="panel">
                            <br>
                            <p style="color: #505050;">Posted: [DATEPOSTED] &nbsp; | &nbsp; Status: [POSTSTATUS]</p>
                            <h4>About this role:</h4>
                            <p>[ROLEDESCRIPTION]</p>

                            <h4>About [COMPANYNAME]:</h4>
                            <p>[COMPANYDESCRIPTION]</p>

                            <br>
                            <a href="pricing.html" class="button btn btn-lg btn-block btn-sm button-black" style="padding-top: 1%; padding-bottom: 1%; width: 200px;">Apply&nbsp; <span class="iconify-inline" data-icon="bi:arrow-right-circle" data-width="15" style="color: white;"></span></a>
                            <br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And CSS:

```
/* LIST STYLES */
    .accordionList {
        background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 18px;
        width: 100%;
        border: none;
        text-align: left;
        outline: none;
        font-size: 15px;
        transition: 0.4s;
    }

    input:focus {
        outline:none !important;
    }
    
    .accordionList:hover {
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
    }
    
    .accordionList:after {
        content: url("img/expand.svg");
        font-size: 10px;
        height: 15px;
        float: right;
        margin-left: 5px;
    }
    
    .activeLink:after {
        content: url("img/close.svg");
    }
    
    .panel {
        padding: 0 18px;
        background-color: white;
        max-height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When load page , JS add event `click` for elements (class name is : `accordionList` )
2. When you get data and create new elements ( those do not add event `click`) and event `click`  of you not working on those elements

You are using Jquery then i suggest you code same as below : (Note : I 've changed stype of `.panel` and records is data example)

```js
$(document).on('click', '.accordionList', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('activeLink')
  $(this).next().toggle(200)
})

const records = [
  {
     logo: 'test',
     company : 'company',
     role: 'role',
     location: 'location',
     dateCreated: 'dateCreated',
     status : 'status',
     roleDescription: 'roleDescription',
     companyDescription: 'companyDescription'
  }
]
$.each(records, function (k, f) {
    let tblRow = "<tr>" + 
    "<td>" + 
        "<div style='padding-top: 1%; padding-bottom: 1%;'>" + 
            "<div style='border: 1px solid black;'>" + 
                "<button class='accordionList' style='font-size: large; outline: none;'>" + 
                    "<span style='padding-top: 2.5%; padding-bottom: 3%;'>" + 
                        "<img src='" + f.logo + "' height='30px'>" + 
                    "</span> &nbsp;<span style='padding-top: 3%; padding-bottom: 3%;'>&nbsp;&nbsp; " + 
                        f.company + " &nbsp; | &nbsp; " + f.role + 
                    " &nbsp;&nbsp; <span style='color: #2b2b2b;''><span class='iconify-inline' data-icon='eva:pin-outline' style='color: #2b2b2b;'></span> " + f.location +"</span></span>" + 
                "</button>" + 
                "<div class='panel'>" + "<br>" + 
                    "<p style='color: #505050;'>Posted: " + f.dateCreated + " &nbsp; | &nbsp; Status: " + f.status + "</p>" + 
                    "<h4>About this role:</h4>" + 
                    "<p>" + f.roleDescription + "</p>" + 
                    "<h4>About " + f.company + ":</h4>" + 
                    "<p>" + f.companyDescription + "</p>" + "<br>" + 
                    "<a href='pricing.html' class='button btn btn-lg btn-block btn-sm button-black' style='padding-top: 1%; padding-bottom: 1%; width: 200px;'>Apply &nbsp; <span class='iconify-inline' data-icon='bi:arrow-right-circle' data-width='15' style='color: white;'></span></a>" + 
                    "<br>" + "</div>" + 
                "</div>" + 
            "</div>" + 
        "</div>" + 
    "</td>" + 
"</tr>"
    $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody")
})
```

```css
.accordionList {
        background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 18px;
        width: 100%;
        border: none;
        text-align: left;
        outline: none;
        font-size: 15px;
        transition: 0.4s;
    }

    input:focus {
        outline:none !important;
    }
    
    .accordionList:hover {
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
    }
    
    .accordionList:after {
        content: url("img/expand.svg");
        font-size: 10px;
        height: 15px;
        float: right;
        margin-left: 5px;
    }
    
    .activeLink:after {
        content: url("img/close.svg");
    }
    
    .panel {
        padding: 0 18px;
        background-color: white;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: none
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="userdata" style="width: 100%;">
    <tbody id="jobsData">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="padding-top: 1%; padding-bottom: 1%;">
                    <div style="border: 1px solid black;">
                        <button class="accordionList" style="font-size: large; outline: none;">
                            <span style="padding-top: 2.5%; padding-bottom: 3%;"><img src="[LOGO]" height="30px"></span>&nbsp;<span style="padding-top: 3%; padding-bottom: 3%;">&nbsp;&nbsp; [COMPANY] &nbsp; | &nbsp; [ROLE] &nbsp;&nbsp; <span style="color: #2b2b2b;"><span class="iconify-inline" data-icon="eva:pin-outline" style="color: #2b2b2b;"></span> [LOCATION]</span></span>
                        </button>
                        <div class="panel">
                            <br>
                            <p style="color: #505050;">Posted: [DATEPOSTED] &nbsp; | &nbsp; Status: [POSTSTATUS]</p>
                            <h4>About this role:</h4>
                            <p>[ROLEDESCRIPTION]</p>

                            <h4>About [COMPANYNAME]:</h4>
                            <p>[COMPANYDESCRIPTION]</p>

                            <br>
                            <a href="pricing.html" class="button btn btn-lg btn-block btn-sm button-black" style="padding-top: 1%; padding-bottom: 1%; width: 200px;">Apply&nbsp; <span class="iconify-inline" data-icon="bi:arrow-right-circle" data-width="15" style="color: white;"></span></a>
                            <br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```
$(document).on('click', '.accordionList', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('activeLink')
  $(this).next().toggle(200)
})
```

event `click` refer from `document` to `.accordionList`

**Update** format your html structure : [image]

Comment: So your code example works as well as my code, except when I add connection from the database it messes it up.

Comment: Please describe in detail the problem with the data from the database

Comment: So I'm pulling in data from a db via NoCodeAPI. As shown in the CSS of my question, I am parsing it on the $.getJSON line in JS section. It displays each row of database in the html table properly, however, the accordion feature doesn't work.

Comment: your `"<tr>" + "<td>" + "<div style='padding-top: 1%; ....` is wrong html structure
.you can change to line by line for easy viewing

Comment: Okay. Let me try that.

Comment: i' ve post image of it